# Why my Dual Boot Win10 x PopOS doesn't work?

Tags: linux, windows-10, dualboot, pop-os

Yesterday I tried for the first time to **Dual boot Windows x Pop OS.** I installed Pop OS, everything worked, but then I **couldn't boot back to Windows**, and after 4 hours I found command `bcdboot C:\Windows /s c: /f ALL` which I entered into **CMD in Windows repair tool** and then I could boot again into Windows. But the problem is, when I tried to go **back to Linux again**, I got the same problem which I had with windows, it said: *"enter proper boot device"*. And now I **don't have access to Linux** (It's still on the HDD, I just can't boot into it).

I have 3 drives, 1 SSD and 2 HDD. I tried to have **Windows on the 240GB SSD + 1TB HDD** and **Linux on 250GB HDD.**

Can you tell me, what possibly could go wrong? And what can I do, to make the Dual Boot work?

I will try to provide any information you will ask me to give you, if you will need them.

**Information:**

- BIOS mode: Legacy (MB doesn't support UEFI)
- sudo os-prober doesn't detect Windows
- GRUB doesn't give option for booting into Windows

**PC:**

- CPU: i7-860
- GPU: GT 1030
- RAM: 12GB DDR3

Comment: Disabling Windows Fast Startup feature is a must when dual-booting. Do that then run os-prober again. Also make sure you're booting from the drive where Grub has been installed. Very likely you installed it (or, better said, let the installer use the default) in the same drive where Windows is installed thus replacing the Windows bootloader that later you repaired. You really NEED to understand the boot process and how to manage it. BIOS mode is always harder because you need to take all the aforementioned variables into account.

Comment: Well, the Linux is installed on the 250GB HDD and Windows on the SSD. So the Windows boot manager should be on the SSD and Grub on the HDD one? Am I mistaken? I am new to this stuff.

Comment: It doesn't have to but it definitely should. This way you can boot both OSes directly and independently just by changing the boot drive order in BIOS, should any of the drives fail. And, of course, you need to familiarize yourself with your BIOS to be able to change settings required for managing boot.

Comment: Tangentially related: If your computer is so old as to have BIOS instead of UEFI then (1) Windows 10 is fine. Barely, it'll be slow and hang a lot but it's doable if regardless of the hardware's vintage you have enough RAM (+8GB recommende) but (2) Pop_OS or any other distro with the Gnome DE is NOT recommended. Lighter flavors like Xubuntu or Lubuntu should be used instead.

Comment: Ok so I disabled "Quick boot" (IG it's the same as fast boot) but I don't have access, to the Linux, I have the same problem I had with Windows. "Please enter proper boot device" how can I repair that, so my Windows will not break again? The Linux is still there, but can't boot into it (So maybe GRUB is broken now?

Comment: You need to change the boot order to the drive you intend to use for Linux *before* installing or set the installer to install Grub in that drive, otherwise it'll install it in the first drive thus overwriting the Windows bootloader. And Fast Boot has nothing to do with **Windows** Fast Startup, the thing that you MUST disable when dual-booting otherwise os-prober (or the Linux installer) won't be able to detect the Windows installation.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know that. So the only thing now is to reinstall the Linux, or how can I install Grub on the HDD from windows? Is there any way how to do that?

Comment: No, you can't "install Grub from Windows". Very likely you need to boot Windows installation media and repair its bootloader before anything else. That's what happen when people think that installing OSes is the same as installing software in Windows (next > next...). Again, you need to know what you're doing before actually doing it.

Comment: Well, my Windows is booting normally from the SSD. So if I now go into BIOS and set boot drive as the HDD one, where I want the Linux, then when I install Linux, GRUB will be on the HDD not SSD and there should not be any problem. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly, but again you MUST disable Fast Startup in Windows (and shutdown properly) before installing Linux. The OS detection for Grub happens during the installation.

Comment: So I should do this? https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

Comment: Yes, exactly. And shutdown afterwards. Then you can change the BIOS boot order to the other drive and reboot in order to choose (temporarily) the USB media with the Linux installer, preferably from the one-time boot menu / boot override menu or any similar name. In any case make sure the installer will install Grub to the other drive so as to not overwrite the Windows one. Most installers allow such selection, just pay attention, it should appear in one of the steps/dialogs.

Comment: Thanks A lot, I appreciate it! I will try so now, and tell you if it's okay.

Comment: Ok I installed Linux and tried to boot into Windows and... EVERYTHING WORKS NOW! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure :) :)

Comment: @Shidori I'm sorry you deleted your last in intelppm - it was interesting.  Disabling intelppm wont kill your computer as its a software governor to reduce power consumption and the CPU has hardware throttling built in.

Comment: @davidgo Well, I guess, I need to learn how to write questions here, since somebody in the comments said, I provided insufficient information under my intelppm question...